# It smells like someone has smoked here or it smells like someone has been smoking here

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

I have come across reviews of hotels where people state that:

"The hotelroom smells like someone has smoked there".

I thought that "someone has smoked there" means that smoking has taken place there, either an hour ago or a year ago.

If it smells like smoke, the smoking must have taken place quite recently. Wouldn't "it smells like someone has been smoking there" be more appropriate, or does that mean someone has just finished their cigarette?

Comment: Yes, it would, but people who post online reviews often don't use the best English! However, it's possible that there might be a residual smell from the soft furnishings in the room rather than actual smoke in the air.

Comment: @Kate Bunting What is the difference between: "someone has been smoking here" and "someone has smoked here recently"? Is "has been smoking"more recent?

Comment: It was you who suggested (correctly) that 'Someone has been smoking' might imply that it was recent. The review you quote doesn't say 'recently'. Since smoking is widely forbidden in public buildings, I thought that a slight smell from furnishings would be very noticeable, at least to a non-smoker, even if it was some time since anyone 'had smoked' there.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I was just wondering if "someone has smoked here recently"  would be idiomatic in this situation.

Comment: It's a valid sentence, but 'has been smoking' would be more natural, in my opinion.