# Why is "have you just farted" okay, but "have you just smoked" not?

Tags: meaning-in-context, present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

If someone has just farted and I can smell it, I can say: "Have you just farted?"

If someone has been smoking and I can smell it, I say: "Have you been smoking?" It is not idiomatic to say: "Have you just smoked?".

Why, what is the reason for this? Is it because smoking lasts longer than a single fart?

Answer (score 2):

A short answer in reference to ing versus ed here.

You are mistaken. It is idiomatic to say: Have you just smoked?

You can also say: Have you been farting?

And if you add **around**, you've got yourself a well-know idiom: Have you been farting around? Instead of working?

I'll leave you to look that up.

Comment: Can you say: "Have you been farting?" for one single fart?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your answer.  Can you say"Have you been singing?" if it was one song? I really don't understand

Comment: So it is possible to say: "have you been farting" for one single fart? Your answers are too cryptic for me.

Comment: @Lambie " If you smell it" - in our house, we say 'who smelt it, dealt it'.

Comment: Lambie@ Farting is a short action. I thought that using the present perfect continous for very short actions imply repetition. Singing or smoking last longer than a few seconds.

Comment: Could you please answer the question: if you can smell that someone has recently farted can you say: "Have you been farting?" even if it is a short activity?

Comment: @anouk I have answered your question at least three times.  If you smell it, you can choose to say: Have you farted? Have you been farting? or Did you fart? I don't know how you can **know** someone has **recently** farted unless you smell it. All three question forms would work. We're back to: It depends on **what you want to say**. YOU.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/271613/it-smells-like-someone-has-smoked-here-or-it-smells-like-someone-has-been-smokin

Comment: "@Lambie Have you been singing? For a single song? At least, that you can hear.  I don't understand this.  If someone has just finished singing one song, can you say: "Have you been singing?" That's what I'd like to know.

Comment: How do you know they have sung one song UNLESS you hear them?? I keep repeating this. The person who sings, is singing or has sung, is NOT the person asking the question. You are. You decide how to ask it. Try to separate those two things.

Comment: @ Lambie I mean is it grammatically correct ?

Answer (score -2):

You would be better saying, *Did you just fart?*  That is the most succinct way.  *Just*, as you use it, means **now, immediately**. You would not ask someone if something just happened using *have*.  You either ask, *Have you farted* or *Did you just fart.*

Regarding the smoking, if someone *just* smoked, you would have seen them doing it.  Why would you ask?  Asking if someone *has been smoking* means *have you smoked recently*.

It makes perfect sense to say, *Did you just smoke before coming into the kitchen,* because now I have qualified my usage of *just* to mean *right before entering the kitchen*.

Comment: Would you use "have you farted" if you can smell the recent fart?

Comment: You might not have seen them smoking. I think her point is about smell not sight.

Comment: I think "Have you just farted?" is fine for British English. (Actually, some would find it vulgar, but that's not because of the perfect.) Regarding your comment "if someone just smoked, you would have seen them doing it", that's not a fair assumption. You might have only just entered the room yourself.

Comment: @rjpond Must you evoke British English here? I fail to see the relevance since all the varieties of English I have seen accept: Have you just [past participle].

Comment: @rjpond How would you answer my original answer? Can you say: "Have you been farting" for one fart?

Comment: @rjpond - You can say anything you like.  For example, *Did, from your bottom, a gas  recently seep?*  You can say that but I would not advise a learner to speak that way.  Check out the link for support of what I'm saying Anouk.  Saying *have you just* sounds clumsy and is not often used, not even in the British Isles. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+you+just%2C+did+you+just&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3

Comment: As a British English speaker, I would _always_ say 'Have you just [verb]ed?' and would regard "Did you just [verb]?' as typically American. (I would say 'Have you been smoking?' because I think of that as a continuing activity.)

Comment: @Michael Harvey When would you say "Have you been farting?" Is it used to express how much it smells?

Comment: @Kate Bunting By "continuing activity" you mean lasting a few minutes? As opposed to a fart that lasts only a  very short time?

Comment: Yes. I've never smoked, but I believe a cigarette lasts for ten minutes or so.